# Forward fill data with conditions

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe, DF, looking like this:

```
    date permno   ret sue  bm gpa
1  202001  10000  0.01 0.4 0.4  NA
2  202002  10000  0.04  NA  NA 0.5
3  202003  10000 -0.01  NA  NA  NA
4  202004  10000  0.00 1.3 0.5  NA
5  202005  10000  0.02  NA  NA 0.3
6  202006  10000  0.01  NA  NA  NA
7  202007  10000  0.03  NA  NA  NA
8  202008  10000 -0.02  NA  NA 0.4
9  202001  11000  0.05 0.1 0.3  NA
10 202002  11000  0.02  NA  NA  NA
11 202003  11000  0.01  NA  NA  NA
12 202004  11000  0.00  NA  NA 0.3
13 202005  11000  0.01  NA  NA  NA
14 202006  11000 -0.01  NA  NA  NA
15 202007  11000  0.04 0.5 0.4  NA
16 202008  11000  0.30  NA  NA  NA
```

I am using this code to forward fill the variables sue, bm and gpa:

```
DF1 <- 
  DF %>%
  arrange(permno,date) %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(sue,bm,gpa)), funs(na.locf(.,na.rm=FALSE)))
```

This results in the following

```
  date permno   ret   sue    bm   gpa

 1 202001  10000  0.01   0.4   0.4  NA  
 2 202002  10000  0.04   0.4   0.4   0.5
 3 202003  10000 -0.01   0.4   0.4   0.5
 4 202004  10000  0      1.3   0.5   0.5
 5 202005  10000  0.02   1.3   0.5   0.3
 6 202006  10000  0.01   1.3   0.5   0.3
 7 202007  10000  0.03   1.3   0.5   0.3
 8 202008  10000 -0.02   1.3   0.5   0.4
 9 202001  11000  0.05   0.1   0.3  NA  
10 202002  11000  0.02   0.1   0.3  NA  
11 202003  11000  0.01   0.1   0.3  NA  
12 202004  11000  0      0.1   0.3   0.3
13 202005  11000  0.01   0.1   0.3   0.3
14 202006  11000 -0.01   0.1   0.3   0.3
15 202007  11000  0.04   0.5   0.4   0.3
16 202008  11000  0.3    0.5   0.4   0.3
```

I want to put a limit on how many months the data is forward filled. I want to forward fill the three variables until the next available value, but maximum 3 months. Thus, the results should look like this:

```
    date permno   ret sue  bm gpa
1  202001  10000  0.01 0.4 0.4  NA
2  202002  10000  0.04 0.4 0.4 0.5
3  202003  10000 -0.01 0.4 0.4 0.5
4  202004  10000  0.00 1.3 0.5 0.5
5  202005  10000  0.02 1.3 0.5 0.3
6  202006  10000  0.01 1.3 0.5 0.3
7  202007  10000  0.03 1.3 0.5 0.3
8  202008  10000 -0.02  NA  NA 0.4
9  202001  11000  0.05 0.1 0.3  NA
10 202002  11000  0.02 0.1 0.3  NA
11 202003  11000  0.01 0.1 0.3  NA
12 202004  11000  0.00 0.1 0.3 0.3
13 202005  11000  0.01  NA  NA 0.3
14 202006  11000 -0.01  NA  NA 0.3
15 202007  11000  0.04 0.5 0.4 0.3
16 202008  11000  0.30 0.5 0.4  NA
```

Does anyone know how I can do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write our own `na.locf()` that allows to make the adjustments you desire:

**Code**

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

na.locf2 <- function(object, period = 3, ...){
  # consecutive NAs
  tmp1 <- rle(is.na(object))
  
  # NA count in the length of the vector 
  tmp2 <- unlist(sapply(tmp1[[1]] , function(x){
          1:x
          }))
  
  # remove all NAs
  tmp3 <- na.locf(object, ...)
  
  # reassign those that are greater than the desired period
  tmp3[tmp2 > period] <- NA
  
  # return 
  tmp3
}

# Then 

DF %>%
  arrange(permno,date) %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(sue,bm,gpa)), funs(na.locf2(.,na.rm=FALSE)))

# Yields

# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   permno [2]
#     date permno   ret   sue    bm   gpa
#    <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 202001  10000  0.01   0.4   0.4  NA  
#  2 202002  10000  0.04   0.4   0.4   0.5
#  3 202003  10000 -0.01   0.4   0.4   0.5
#  4 202004  10000  0      1.3   0.5   0.5
#  5 202005  10000  0.02   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  6 202006  10000  0.01   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  7 202007  10000  0.03   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  8 202008  10000 -0.02  NA    NA     0.4
#  9 202001  11000  0.05   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 10 202002  11000  0.02   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 11 202003  11000  0.01   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 12 202004  11000  0      0.1   0.3   0.3
# 13 202005  11000  0.01  NA    NA     0.3
# 14 202006  11000 -0.01  NA    NA     0.3
# 15 202007  11000  0.04   0.5   0.4   0.3
# 16 202008  11000  0.3    0.5   0.4  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a rolling-window thing. Since you need to limit the carry-forward, though, one problem is that when you look at a particular cell, its predecessor has already been *fixed* (un-`NA`'d), so we need to look at the vector in `rev`erse.

A helper function, where `2:4` is based on your preference for no more than three months. In the context of a reversed `rollapply`, `z[1]` in this case is likely an `NA` with `z[2:4]` being the three *preceding* months.

```r
func <- function(z) if (is.na(z[1])) na.omit(z[2:4])[1] else z[1]
```

Since we're using `partial=TRUE` in the rolling, it is feasible that `z` will not be length-4; this is fine, though, since even `z[100000]` will return `NA`, which is explicitly handled by `na.omit`. (This condition can also be addressed with a test on `length(z)`.)

Another note: `na.omit(.)` can return a length-0 vector, which is obviously bad in this context. However, adding `[1]` after it forces it to return an `NA`, which is what we need it to be if no non-`NA` elements exist within `z[2:4]`.

From here, most of the work is done by `zoo::rollapply`:

```r
DF %>%
  arrange(permno, date) %>%
  group_by(permno) %>%
  mutate(across(sue:gpa, ~ rev(zoo::rollapply(rev(.), 4, align="left", FUN = func, partial = TRUE)))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 16 x 6
#      date permno   ret   sue    bm   gpa
#     <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 202001  10000  0.01   0.4   0.4  NA  
#  2 202002  10000  0.04   0.4   0.4   0.5
#  3 202003  10000 -0.01   0.4   0.4   0.5
#  4 202004  10000  0      1.3   0.5   0.5
#  5 202005  10000  0.02   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  6 202006  10000  0.01   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  7 202007  10000  0.03   1.3   0.5   0.3
#  8 202008  10000 -0.02  NA    NA     0.4
#  9 202001  11000  0.05   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 10 202002  11000  0.02   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 11 202003  11000  0.01   0.1   0.3  NA  
# 12 202004  11000  0      0.1   0.3   0.3
# 13 202005  11000  0.01  NA    NA     0.3
# 14 202006  11000 -0.01  NA    NA     0.3
# 15 202007  11000  0.04   0.5   0.4   0.3
# 16 202008  11000  0.3    0.5   0.4  NA
```